# The procedure Entry point isgraph

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I install xampp and my windows 8.1
Ichange port of apache to 81
Apache doesn't work with me and send me this error

> **The procedure entry point isgraph
> Doesn:tlocated in the dynamic library xampp/apache/pcre2-8.dll**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in the PHP error logs.
It might have to do with ts/nts versions.
e.g, `[02-Aug-2022 18:33:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: curl: Unable to initialize module Module compiled with build ID=API20180731,NTS,VC15 PHP    compiled with build ID=API20180731,TS,VC15`